# www A record will not update to non-www A record?

Tags: dns, domain-registration

I recently moved a website from an existing server (not GoDaddy) to a new GoDaddy server, and also transferred the domain name between GoDaddy accounts.

However, only the non-www domain seems to point to the new server. If I access the www version, I get the old site. I've looked in the DNS Zone Editor for the domain and the old IP address is nowhere to be found. I even added a 'www' A record pointing to the new IP address hoping that would help.

I'm a bit lost as to why it's not updating, any ideas?

Comment: How long ago did you make the change?

Comment: It's been nearly about a month now. Since the old server is still running for now, I was just letting it sit to see if it was just a delay in propagation, but this seems to be an excessive amount of time.

Comment: Indeed, it definitely shouldn't take more than a couple of days. At this point we'd probably need to know your domain name to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks. 

greenbridgerealestate.com is the domain in question

Comment: Where is the 'DNS Zone editor' in which you're editing the records? Your domain's DNS is using *.microsoftonline.com name servers.

Comment: I'm using the GoDaddy editor, since the domain is registered there. The Microsoft nameservers are for the mail system being used on the domain, handled via an IT company. If the issue is from there, I can get in contact with them and see if they can dig further in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is hinted at in your last comment. It doesn't matter where the domain is registered - DNS for your domain is handled by whatever the nameservers point to. In your case, this is Microsoft (I assume you're using Office 365 or something like that). Changing DNS entries in GoDaddy won't have any effect, as you're not using them for DNS.

I've not used Office 365 but if they're hosting your DNS, I'd hope they would give you a way to add DNS records (or some other way to solve this). I'd suggest getting in touch with your IT company to see what they suggest.